# Filling single value by using fillna()

Tags: python, missing-data, fillna

**Hello**,

I'm trying to replace a missing value by using **fillna()** , yet I keep getting an error:

```
gaming.loc[16448, 'year_of_release'].fillna(2012.0, inplace=True)
```

I'm getting an AttributeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_31/422732767.py in <module>
----> 1 gaming.loc[16448, 'year_of_release'].fillna(2012.0, inplace=True)

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Comment: 'fillna()' is a method that applies to a dataframe, but what you do is applying it to a single value in the DF, thus a numpy value.
What you can do is: an 'if-else' statement if it's only for a specific value, or apply 'fillna()' to the whole column

Answer (score -1):

1. `gaming.loc[x, y]` returns a single value, not a Series or Dataframe. Try `gaming.loc[[x], [y]]` to get a Dataframe back.
2. I think `.loc` returns a copy, so instead of doing an inplace operation you would need to `df.loc[[x], [y]] = df.loc[[x], [y]].fillna(2012.0)`